# Checking to see if struct array is full

Tags: c, arrays, loops, structure

I'm writing a code that allows the user to input information for up to 2 employees however, if the user tries to add another employee when the array is already holding information for 2 employees, an error message should appear. At the moment the code seems to just overwrite the employee information instead of outputting an error message.

Also, as the code currently is, you have to input both sets of employee data before the menu appears. Is there any way to have it so you enter a set of employee data and then the menu appears? Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 2
// Define Number of Employees "SIZE" to be 2

struct Employee{
    int ID;
    int AGE;
    double SALARY;
};
//Declare Struct Employee


/* main program */
int main(void) {

    int option = 0;
    int i;
    struct Employee emp[SIZE];

    printf("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n\n");

    // Declare a struct Employee array "emp" with SIZE elements
    // and initialize all elements to zero

    do {
            // Print the option list
            printf("\n");
            printf("1. Display Employee Information\n");
            printf("2. Add Employee\n");
            printf("0. Exit\n\n");
            printf("Please select from the above options: ");

            // Capture input to option variable
            scanf("%d",&option);
            printf("\n");

            switch (option) {
                    case 0: // Exit the program
                            printf("Exiting Employee Data Program. Goodbye!!!\n");

                            break;
                    case 1: // Display Employee Data
                            // @IN-LAB

                          printf("EMP ID EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n");
                          printf("====== ======= ==========\n");

                          //Use "%6d%9d%11.21f" formatting in a
                          //printf statement to display
                          //employee id, age and salary of
                          //all employees using a loop construct

                          for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
                                  printf("%d    %d   %11.2lf", emp[i].ID, emp[i].AGE, emp[i].SALARY);
 }

                          //The loop construct will be run for SIZE times
                          //and will only display Employee data
                          //where the EmployeeID is > 0

                          break;
                  case 2: //Adding Employee
                                    // @IN-LAB

                          printf("Adding Employee\n");
                          printf("===============\n");

                          if (emp[i].ID > emp[SIZE]) {
                                  printf("Full");
                          }

                          for(i=0;i>SIZE;i++) {
                                  printf("Error");
                          }

                          for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {

                          printf("\nEnter employee ID: ");
                          scanf ("%d", &emp[i].ID);

                          printf("\nEnter employee Age: ");
                          scanf ("%d", &emp[i].AGE);

                          printf("\nEnter employee Salary: ");
                          scanf ("%11lf", &emp[i].SALARY);
                                  }


                          //Check for limits on the array and add employee
                          //data accordingly

                          break;

                  default:

                          printf("ERROR: Incorrect Option: Try Again\n\n");

            }

    } while (option!= 0);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). SO is not a debugging service. When you identify the problem with your program's logic, if a certain behavior of your code still leaves you wondering, then by all means post a question.

Comment: Thanks for this, did not know something like this existed. I will be sure to use it when I run into problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a variable loop that is used to leave the `while` loop when the user enters 0 as an option.
Another variable `number_of_employees` is added to keep track of the number of employees. It is initialized to 0 & incremented every time a new user is added.

```
int option = 0;
int i;
int loop = 1; /* This variable is used to terminate the programme by exiting the while loop */
int number_of_employees = 0; /* We add this variable that increments every time a new employee is added */
struct Employee emp[SIZE];

printf("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n\n");

// Declare a struct Employee array "emp" with SIZE elements
// and initialize all elements to zero

while(loop) {
        // Print the option list
        printf("\n");
        printf("1. Display Employee Information\n");
        printf("2. Add Employee\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");

        // Capture input to option variable
        scanf("%d",&option);
        printf("\n");

        switch (option) {
                case 0: // Exit the program
                        printf("Exiting Employee Data Program. Goodbye!!!\n");  
                        loop = 0; // Exiting
                break;

                case 1: // Display Employee Data
                        // @IN-LAB

                      printf("EMP ID EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n");
                      printf("====== ======= ==========\n");

                      //Use "%6d%9d%11.21f" formatting in a
                      //printf statement to display
                      //employee id, age and salary of
                      //all employees using a loop construct

                      for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
                              printf("%d    %d   %11.2lf", emp[i].ID, emp[i].AGE, emp[i].SALARY);
                      }

                      //The loop construct will be run for SIZE times
                      //and will only display Employee data
                      //where the EmployeeID is > 0

                break;

                case 2: //Adding Employee
                                // @IN-LAB

                      printf("Adding Employee\n");
                      printf("===============\n");

                       /* This is how to check if we can add an employee */
                      if (number_of_employees < size) {

                        printf("\nEnter employee ID: ");
                        scanf ("%d", &emp[number_of_employees].ID);

                        printf("\nEnter employee Age: ");
                        scanf ("%d", &emp[number_of_employees].AGE);

                        printf("\nEnter employee Salary: ");
                        scanf ("%11lf", &emp[number_of_employees].SALARY);

                        /* Inceremeting */
                        number_of_employees++;
                      }

                      else {
                        printf("Full");
                      }

                      //Check for limits on the array and add employee
                      //data accordingly

              break;

              default:

                      printf("ERROR: Incorrect Option: Try Again\n\n");

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can debug with normal printf() statements, atleast for this code.
The comparison to check full has issues as why will you compare `int` with `struct` type here `if (emp[i].ID > emp[SIZE])`

I would suggest the following :

Initialize your integer with 0 value :

```
int i = 0;
```

Use a different counter suppose j for displaying the content of array, so that you save the value of i

```
for(int j = 0;j<SIZE;j++) {
   printf("%d    %d   %11.2lf\n", emp[j].ID, emp[j].AGE, emp[j].SALARY);
 }
```

Check with i for fullness

```
if(i >= SIZE) {
    printf("Full");
    break;
}
```